# Regular Expression in burp

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a forward proxy called Burp and would like to see only results from google in my site scope.

What will be the regex for if i want to see `*.google.*` in my result

So sample output can be

```
www.google.com
drive.google.com 
google.in
```

and so on

Comment: `(.)*\.{0,1}google\.(.)+` you can test it here http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Quite simply, just `google`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
^.*?google\..*$
```

Will match anything before and after `.google.`

Comment: Will that match "google.in"? That was one OP listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*\.domain\.com$

^.*\.test\.domain\.com$
```

^ -> Signifies beginning of the regex

.* -> accept anything

. -> Escape sequence for dot

$ -> End Regex